# Lost Packets And Duplicate Packets Scenario in Three way Hand-shaking

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, tcp

In the process of 3 way hand-shaking between a client and a server, what will happen in the following scenarios? Thanks.

Lost (control) packets:

1. What happen if SYN lost?  client vs. server actions
2. What happen if SYN+ACK lost? client vs. server actions
3. What happen if ACK  lost? client vs. server actions

Duplicate (control) packets:

4. What does server do if duplicate SYN received?
5. What does client do if duplicate SYN+ACK received?
6. What does server do if duplicate ACK received?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What happen if SYN lost?

It is retransmitted by the client if it hasn't been acknowledged by the server with a SYN-ACK.

> 2. What happen if SYN+ACK lost?

The SYN is retransmitted by the client if it hasn't been acknowledged by the server with a SYN-ACK.

> 3. What happen if ACK lost?

The SYN-ACK is retransmitted by the server if it hasn't been acknowledged by the client with an ACK.

> 4. What does server do if duplicate SYN received?

It retransmits the SYN-ACK.

> 5. What does client do if duplicate SYN+ACK received?

It retransmits the ACK.

> 6. What does server do if duplicate ACK received?

Nothing.